# Records Doesn't Appear in Table reporting services 2008

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008

When I use table in reporting services 2008 and dragging fields into it,
it shows repeated records of column header, not values.

What's wrong here ?

[image]

Instead of displaying the field values in the output, it is displaying the field names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fields in dataset was calculated fields, it must be query fields